# Foundation - is there a way to show page for small and large only?

Tags: grid, zurb-foundation, visibility

I would like to show specific page for small and large screens and different for medium screen for example:

```
<div class="show-for-small-only">
    loading main page
 </div>
<div class="show-for-large-only">
    loading main page
</div>
<div class="show-for-medium-only">  
    specific medium page here
</div>
```

Is there alternative to this in ZURB Foundation? Without loading the same page twice? Like this

```
<div class="show-for-small-only show-for-large-only"></div>
```

which apparently doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is quite simple. Just hide the main page for medium screens only and the specific page for medium screens show only for medium screens like this:

```
<div class="hide-for-medium-only">
    loading main page
 </div>
<div class="show-for-medium-only">  
    specific medium page here
</div>
```